# Thread problem with Druby and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, druby

I have a rails app and a separate druby process. This process gives me some methods, and at the first line of each druby's method there is a call to ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection, where the db_name depends on a param set by the rails application.
Sometimes the process is getting the wrong database name and I think it could be a concurrency problem. Could it be? Any idea on how to make it thread-safe?

Thanks for any help!
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a concurrency problem.

To fix it, you would have to change your architecture a little bit, but I don't have enough informations.

- Is the code running in the backend the same as the one running in your rails application ?
- Do your different databases use the same model ?
- How many different databases you have ? Does this number grow ?

Basically, if you have a small and fixed number of databases, the simplest is to use different ruby processes.

If you have different databases with different models, you could envisions to use different base classes:

```
AppA < ActiveRecord::Base
Model1 < AppA
Model2 < AppA

AppB < ActiveRecord::Base
Model3 < AppB
```

Then you can call

```
AppA.establish_connection(...)
AppB.establish_connection(...)
```

to different databases.

Comment: You could also add a global Mutex to serialize your drb requests, but then you limit the speed.